# How to keep track of a continously changing file when being used by multiple users

Tags: python, database, edit, remote-access

I apologize if the question is a little vague but I'm trying to find the simplest way to do this.

I have a small group of people, for whom I have written a python script. Now this python script summarizes articles mined from a website (that are unique by an id number) when the user runs it with some parameters. Now each user might choose to "claim" one or more articles, which means that they will be working on it. Thus any future execution of the script should omit using a "claimed" article in its summary.

- I need a way to have a globally accessible file, which my script accesses and checks its output against.
- I also need to have a way for the user to add multiple id numbers to this global file.

I understand that a rudimentary database might be the best way to go, but is there a simpler way to read and edit files remotely over python? I can host this file on my personal webspace, but I'm not sure of what would be the simplest way to edit and read it since I'm relatively new to python.

The number of users is small and constant so it does not have to be very robust, just needs to work.

Language: Python

Thanks!

Comment: How many articles might be claimed at any one time?

Comment: It can be just one and it can be a batch of 20. It depends on the quality of articles which were summarized that they are looking at.

Comment: I really recommend you use the [`sqlite3`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) module, it's very simple and for a small number of simultaneous write requests it will perform fine (it just locks the database file).